# How to use SUM function one column with MAX function another column (example inside)

Tags: sql, sum, max

For example i have data:

```
 ColumnID | YEAR | SUM | Specified
----------+------+-----+-----------
 1        | 2014 | 34  |  0          -- Row with MAX(Specified)
----------+------+-----+-----------
 2        | 2014 | 45  |  0
 2        | 2014 | 67  |  1          -- Row with MAX(Specified)
----------+------+-----+-----------
 3        | 2014 | 35  |  1
 3        | 2014 | 67  |  2          -- Row with MAX(Specified)
 3        | 2014 | 23  |  0
```

I need sum by ColumnID taking max of Specified column

finally i must have 34 + 67 + 67 = 168 (ColumnID 1, 2, 3 with Specified 0, 1, 2)

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the ANSI-standard window functions.  This let's you do exactly what you want:

```
select max(sum)
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by columnID order by specified desc) as seqnum
      from example e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as well try this.

```
SELECT sum(eachmax) FROM
(SELECT MAX(sum) AS eachmax FROM `tbl` group by columnID) as temp
```

**OUTPUT**

```
168
```

Comment: Thank you james jelo4kul! Your answer is true

Comment: It's a pleasure answering. Accepting the answer would be appreciated

Comment: I have little reputation) sorry. I will save your name for the future))

Comment: No problem. Thanks in advance